# Unbale to remove event listeners in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener

I am trying to add custom event listeners at the making of the page and trying to remove the events when going out of the page.
I am getting issues with this

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Event registry returned null for event **PageButtonEvent** ; Zone: Zone_action ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Event registry returned null for event **PageButtonEvent**
```

Addition of listener:

```
constructor(context) {
      window.addEventListener('PageButtonEvent', this.navigateToPage.bind(this), false);
      window.addEventListener('PageUserButtonEvent', this.navigateToUserPage.bind(this), false);
}
```

Removal of listener:

```
removeWindowEvents() {
     window.removeEventListener('PageButtonEvent', this.navigateToPage, false);
     window.removeEventListener('PageUserButtonEvent', this.navigateToUserPage, false);
}
```

Let me know if anymore details are needed.

Comment: You need to use the same function object when removing as when adding. Since you added a bound function, you have to remove the same bound function. This always requires giving a name to the function, so you can use the same name in both calls.

Comment: Since `Function.bind()` returns a copy of the function, you'll have to assign it to a variable first.